# Have I found a bug in java.util.ArrayList.containsAll?

Tags: java, list, collections, arraylist

In Java I've two lists:

```
List<Satellite> sats = new ArrayList<Satellite>();
List<Satellite> sats2 = new ArrayList<Satellite>();

Satellite sat1 = new Satellite();
Satellite sat2 = new Satellite();

sats.add(sat1);

sats2.add(sat1);
sats2.add(sat2);
```

When I do the following containsAll method on the first list:

```
sats.containsAll(sats2); //Returns TRUE!
```

It returns true. But the first List (sats) only contains 1 item and the second list contains 2. Therefor it's not even possible that the first list (sats) containsAll items from the second list (sats2). Any idea why or is this a bug in the Java JDK?

I've read in another StackOverflow question that this is not the most performant way to do something like this, so if anyone has a suggestion on how to make it more performant that would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you override the `equals` method of your Satellite class? If yes show us the code (and maybe the `hashCode` method as well)

Comment: [The first rule of programming; Its always your fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)

Comment: hashCode doesn't matter here. .. but equals sure does.

Comment: The second rule of programming; Except when it isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by @Progman, you're probably overriding the `equals` method in `Satellite`.

The program below prints `false`.

```
import java.util.*;

class Satellite {
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Satellite> sats = new ArrayList<Satellite>();
        List<Satellite> sats2 = new ArrayList<Satellite>();

        Satellite sat1 = new Satellite();
        Satellite sat2 = new Satellite();

        sats.add(sat1);

        sats2.add(sat1);
        sats2.add(sat2);

        System.out.println(sats.containsAll(sats2));
    }
}
```

([ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/Zzavc))

I suggest that you print the contents of the two lists and check that the content corresponds to what you expect it to be.

Comment: It was indeed an error in a generated equals method. Little bit stupid of me not to check ... Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

For many classes, it makes sense that two objects created the same way (e.g. `new Satellite()`) would be considered equal. Keep in mind that `containsAll` doesn't care about the number of copies of an object that a `Collection` contains, just that it contains at least one of each *distinct* element in the `Collection` that it's given. So for example, if you had a `List a` that contained `[A, A]` and a list `b` that just contained `[A]`, `b.containsAll(a)` and `a.containsAll(b)` would both return `true`. This is probably analogous to what's happening here.

Answer (score 1):

Too late to reply but the second part of your question - a more efficient way to do containsAll is : CollectionUtils.isSubCollection(subSet, superSet)
That is O(n^2) vs O(n) complexity