# Having trouble comparing an ArrayList of Strings with a String array

Tags: java, arraylist

Firstly I created the ArrayList of Strings:

`List<List<String>> array1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();`

Then after populating it with data and doing a print:

```
[John, Smith, 120]
[Albert, Einstein, 170]
```

Now I want to loop through the list and do a comparison with say `String[] array2 = {"Albert", "Einstein", "170"}` and I've tried so far:

`if (array1.get(i).equals(array2)) { blah }`

However this is not working, I basically want traverse the arraylist and find if my array2 gets a match or not. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A list simply *isn't* equal to an array. The simplest fix for this would be to wrap your array in a list first:

```
if (array1.get(i).equals(Arrays.asList(array2))
```

That will then use the `equals` implementation which just performs sequential equality checking on each item.

If you just want to find the *first* matching entry, then using `indexOf` as per Louis's answer will also work.

I would also strongly suggest that you *don't* call a variable `array1` when it's not an array.

Finally, if you're using `List<String>` just as a wrapper to avoid having to create a *real* data structure with (say) names and ages in, then don't: create a `Person` class, so you end up with:

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
Person testPerson = new Person("Albert", "Einstein", 170);
```

... implement equality and hashing appropriately, and you'll be good to go. Your code will be *much* simpler to read and maintain that way.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on some good practices, as a beginner I appreciate this kind of help!

Comment: If I can just squeeze in a little question here: I want to traverse the list and look for people with > 130 IQ (so the third element) however I'm stuck as numerical values are stored as characters. Any way around this? Also how do I reference the third element `array1.get(i)[2]` (a wild guess)?

Comment: @meiryo: As I said at the end: don't deal with strings, create a class representing the data. That will solve *both* of your problems, as you'll have the age as an integer, and you won't need to remember the magic number of an index.

Answer (score 2):

```
return listOfListsOfStrings.indexOf(Arrays.asList(arrayOfStrings));
```

would find out if there are any matches for that array in the list.  It returns i, if the ith list matches the array, and -1 if no matches are found.  You don't even need a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

As per your given example both are lists. So try if you can work out with list1.containsAll(list2) i.e, conatinsAll method. Hope it helps

There is also an example here [Have I found a bug in java.util.ArrayList.containsAll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708445/have-i-found-a-bug-in-java-util-arraylist-containsall)